# Change the tomcat session id to include upper and lower case char

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I have a requirement that need to make sure the session id format generated by the Tomcat should include both upper, lower case char and 0-9.
I check the source code of Tomcat.
\org\apache\catalina\util\StandardSessionIdGenerator.java

In the method public String generateSessionId(String route)

There are few line to render the byte to String of hex digit as following:

```
byte b1 = (byte) ((random[j] & 0xf0) >> 4);
byte b2 = (byte) (random[j] & 0x0f);
if (b1 < 10)
    buffer.append((char) ('0' + b1));
else
    buffer.append((char) ('A' + (b1 - 10)));
if (b2 < 10)
    buffer.append((char) ('0' + b2));
else
    buffer.append((char) ('A' + (b2 - 10)));
```

Looks like that when changing the capital 'A' to 'a', then I can achieve my goal.(the goal is the generated session id would contain both A-Z,a-z and 0-9)

The generated session id after changed:

6B95cDf17411a9555D0E42d99C8E0292

Is this a simple and valid change or do you see any potential concern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a quite strange type of requirement - the important thing here is the length of the underlying session ID, not how it's encoded (there's a difference between a random ID like this and for example a password that a user selects). If the session ID:s generated by Tomcat aren't deemed secure enough the best option would probably be to simply raise the value of the [`sessionIdLength`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/sessionidgenerator.html) parameter.

With that said, if you really need to generate your own ID then a custom `org.apache.catalina.SessionIdGenerator` (possibly extending the `StandardSessionIdGenerator`) would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable thoughts. But the requirement is that for some reason the generated ID should be on that format, of course the requirement also ask for length and the byte length. Tomcat default generated session id is complaint for this part, only the format would need to tweak.

Comment: The requirement I mentioned
[link]https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/web_server_security_requirements_guide/2015-08-28/finding/V-41809

Comment: That's still a bad requirement - the ID isn't generated by randomly picking characters (in that case it would make sense) but a certain number of bytes are picked randomly and then encoded.

But sure, sometimes we need to adhere to bad requirements as well.

Comment: The Tomcat's session id is first, get SecureRandom, then encode hex digit as  string. I think it is secure. The original question is, if we change that to make the final encoded string contains upper/lower/number by using that approach(slightly modify like I mentioned), would it cause any problem?

Comment: As long as the resulting string can be included in a URL without escaping (and the proposed change would still allow that) I can't imagine any problem. You won't have increased security but you will adhere to the requirement (at least with some probability - you could of course end up with a generated ID that only contains upper or lower case characters but the likelihood is low).

I ran a test just for fun and out of 1000000 attempts about 9994600 contained both an uppercase and a lowercase character.